# How to set the placeholder for password field in ie7 or higher

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show some default text like "Enter your password " in password field. As I need to support IE7, the placeholder attribute is no solution here. I  used onfocus and blur but it doesn't work in internet explorer.

```
<input type="text" value="Enter the password" id="fieldPassword" onfocus="showPass()" onblur="hidePass()"/>
```

```
function showPass()
{
    var pass = document.getElementById('fieldPassword').value;
    if((pass=="Enter the password")||pass=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('fieldPassword').type="password";
        document.getElementById('fieldPassword').value="";   
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

function hidePass()
{
    var pass = document.getElementById('fieldPassword').value;
    if(pass=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('fieldPassword').type="text";
        document.getElementById('fieldPassword').value="Enter the password";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens in internet explorer?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `placeholder` attribute? That's exactly what it's designed for.

Comment: @JamesAllardice the placeholder attr is HTML5 and not viable in IE < 10 see [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) for reference.

Comment: I changed field type by using javascript but it doesn't work in ie 7

Comment: @MihaiStancu - I know, but you can feature detect it and fall back where necessary. There are [various polyfills](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) that will allow it to work in older browsers too.

Comment: `if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7)` will detect IE7 in JQuery, so you can use the normal version suggested by Mihai below for all modern browsers and then something custom just for IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/9GTcL/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="placeholder">
    <input type="password" id="pswdInput" />
    <input type="text" value="Enter password..." id="textInput" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text=document.getElementById('textInput'),
    pswd=document.getElementById('pswdInput');
text.onfocus=pswd.onfocus=function(){
    text.style.display='none';
    pswd.focus();
}
pswd.onblur=function(){
    if(pswd.value==''){
        text.style.display='block';
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.placeholder{
    position:relative;
}
.placeholder>#textInput{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.placeholder>input{
    width:140px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to achieve this you must use an

```
<input type='text' value='Enter your password' />
```

And on click/focus you will change the type of the input element to

```
<input type='password' />
```

On blur if there is no change in the value you will change it back to the text type. You can also achieve this using 2 different inputs which you show/hide but in that case you have to trigger focus on the newly visible element and you can't use the same id for both.

Comment: You can't change the 'type' attribute in the old versions of IE for security reasons. If you look at the JavaScript console you'll see a security exception when you try. "Access is denied" and all that.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a js file I use to have placeholders in IE just [download](http://www.mediafire.com/?ug3sj9zafbbaxmj) it and link it in the header of your page and then add this piece of code just before the ending body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();</script>
```